# How to create a command file in SQL with foreign keys referencing a table with two primary keys?

Tags: mysql

I am doing a project for my database management class and I can not figure out how to create a file command for a table creating in SQL. We have two entities with two primary keys and I can not get the table created. I was wondering if you had any input? The travel agency table has two primary keys and it is a foreign key in these tables and I can not get these tables to create for some reason and I can not figure it out. Here is what I have thus far:
These are tables with a foreign key that references a table with two primary keys:

```
create table rental  (rental_id integer not null,  
max_daily_mileage integer not null,  
is_unlimited_mileage char(3) not null,  
rental_start_date integer not null,  
rental_end_date integer not null,  
is_reservation_a_hold char(3),  
checked_out_mileage integer not null,  
checked_in_mileage integer not null,  
checked_out_condition char(8) not null,  
checked_in_condition char(8) not null,  
company_discount integer,  
reservation_is_cancelled char(3),  
employee_id_booked integer not null,  
employee_id_checked_out_car integer not null,  
employee_id_checked_in_car integer not null,  
discount_id integer not null,  
customer_id integer not null,  
class_id integer not null,  
car_id integer not null,  
franchise_id integer not null,  
company_id integer not null, 
primary key (rental_id), 
foreign key (discount_id) references frequent_renter_discount (discount_id), 
foreign key (customer_id) references customers (customer_id), 
foreign key (travel_agency_id) references travel_agency (travel_agency_id), 
foreign key (car_id) references car (car_id), 
foreign key (franchise_id) references franchise (franchise_id), 
foreign key (company_id) references company (company_id));  

create table customers 
(customer_id integer not null, 
employer char(15) not null, 
id_verified integer, 
employee_id integer not null,  
corporate_account_id integer not null, 
credit_card_id integer not null,  
company_id integer not null, 
primary key (customer_id), 
foreign key (employee_id) references employees (employee_id), 
foreign key (corporate_account_id) references corporate_account (corporate_account_id), foreign key (credit_card_id) references credit_card (credit_card_id), 
foreign key (company_id) references company (company_id),
foreign key (rental_id) references rental (rental_id));
```

Table with two primary keys:

```
create table travel_agency  
(travel_agency_id integer not null,  
travel_agent_id integer not null,  
location char(15) not null,  
company_id integer not null,  
primary key (travel_agency_id,travel_agent_id), 
foreign key (company_id) references company (company_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just can't add a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT on just a part of a composite PRIMARY KEY.
(By the way, there's no field `travel_agency_id integer` in table rental definition...)

If you wanna reference a composite PK, you'll have to add a reference to all fields composing the key.

Which would mean, for table rental

```
CREATE TABLE rental  (
rental_id integer not null,  
--...,
travel_agency_id integer,
travel_agent_id integer,
PRIMARY KEY (rental_id), 
--...,
FOREIGN KEY (travel_agency_id, travel_agent_id) 
   REFERENCES travel_agency(travel_agency_id, travel_agent_id)
);
```

Or change your design, use a surrogate key, and add a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on fields for which combinations should be unique, for example.

In general, I would try to avoid composite keys, by the way.